# Solved but not explained: Qt5.5 webkitwidgets, missing DLL, unexpected crash

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll

I made a very simple and boring postal code -> city lookup program (it uses an online api).

I wanted to add functionality which allows to select any country (which the api can process). For this I wanted to load the main page and parse the DOM to get all the countries. This requires webkitwidgets. http://www.zippopotam.us/#where (this is the table I want to extract the information from)

Unfortunately, when attempting to run the program it never even starts and gives me the Application Output:

```
Starting ZipcodeToLocation.exe...
The program has unexpectedly finished.
ZipcodeToLocation.exe crashed
```

So I try running the debugger:

```
An exception was triggered: 
Exception at 0x77cbd4f2, code: 0xc0000135: DLL not found, flags=0x0.
During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135.
```

Weird... so I try finding this error message on the internet and nothing really helps me. I think maybe I set something up wrong, so I open the webkitwidgets examples and compile those. When attempting to run - same error.

Using programs like some dependency walker didn't really help me much either.

I ran the MaintananceTool to check whether I was missing something, but I wasn't able to detect anything.

Im running QtCreator on Windows btw.

My .pro

```
QT += core gui webkitwidgets network

CONFIG += c++14

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = ZipcodeToLocation
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        MainWindow.cpp

HEADERS  += MainWindow.hpp

FORMS    += MainWindow.ui
```

If I remove the following portion from my main window ctor, everything runs es expected:

```
auto page = new QWebPage(this);
page->mainFrame()->load(QUrl("http://www.zippopotam.us"));
```

Note: this is currently the only section using webkitwidgets.

I would be really happy if someone could help me overcome this roadblock and has any suggestions on what might be going wrong.

Edit: Just to make it complete, a screenshot of the depends run: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyYF1.png
The german part translates to "The System can't find specified file".

Edit2: If you have QtCreator installed and want to attempt reproducing my error, create new QWidgets application, edit your .pro like so:
`QT       += core gui webkitwidgets`

and this line at the end of MainWindow ctor (probably any usage of webkitwidgets would do):

```
#include <QWebKitWidgets>
//...
QWebPage *page = new QWebPage(this);
```

Edit3: As a reaction to a recent comment, I tried copying all dlls from the Qt directory to the .exe location (release) and tried running it from there. It said "Missing Qt5Positioning.dll". Which is weird, because I am not using the location module... But I guess that explains the missing dll crash?

Edit4:
I finally had enough and simply completely reinstalled Qt from scratch. Somehow my installation had to be messed up, because after that the problem vanished.

Comment: Did you supply Webkit Qt dll to your release software? Do you encounter this problem in debug-mode too=

Comment: I don't see why you ask specifically for the webkit dll, since I am using webkitwidgets, which has other dependencies, too. And I am pretty sure I don't have to copy any dlls when running from inside QtCreator, since it knows where the dlls are located. Just to prove a point, I actually did copy Webkit Qt dll to the respective working directory - no change. The results for running/debugging in debug mode are identical to release mode as far as I can  tell